# How to get whole terms of more than 1 word from option-list into consecutive input-fields

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have an html-form to read out data from a database. Values for DB-request can be chosen from an option list and are sent  to input-fields. On demand, additional input-fields can be created. This works well with the following functions when the selected values are single words:

```
enter code here

  <script>
  // Start of function for additional input fields  
     var counter = 1;

     var limit = 10;

     function addInput(divName){

          if (counter == limit)  {

               alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " 
  inputs");

          }

          else {

     // Create new div
     var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = '<br><input type="text" name="productinput[]" 
  class="awesomplete" list="productinputselect" size="20"/>';
     document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

     // Re instantiate Awesomplete
     new Awesomplete(newdiv.querySelector('input'), { list: 
  document.querySelector('#productinputselect') });

     // Set counter
     counter++;

          }

     }

  // End of function for additional input fields  


  // Start of function for sending selected values to input-field   

  function getSelectValues(select) {
    var result = [];
    var options = select && select.options;
    var opt;

    for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      opt = options[i];

      if (opt.selected) {
        result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
      }
    }
    return result;
   }

  function sendproductnameinput() {
    var index = 0;
          var inputs = document.formdatabaseDE.elements["productinput[]"];
      var selected = getSelectValues(document.formdatabase.productselect);

      // set the input values based on the selected options
      for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
          if(index < inputs.length) {
              inputs[index].value = selected[i];
          index++;
          }
      }

          // empty the remaining inputs
          for (var i = selected.length; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                  inputs[i].value = '';
          }
  }

  // End of function for sending selected values to input-field   
   </script>
```

However, if a value from the option-list is composed by 2 or more words (separated by single space), only the first word is sent to the input field and not the whole term.

I would be more than happy, if someone could help me to modify this function so that the values are completely sent to the input fields, although if they contain more than 1 word.

Comment: could you add a simple pnkr/jsbin to this example?

Comment: @inoabrian it is curious, in this working fiddle jsfiddle.net/586menbv/19/, it works as it should! My Option-list is generated by the following DB-query: $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_main ORDER BY Name";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo '<option class="optproduct" value='. $row['Name'] . '>' . $row['Name']. '</option>';
     echo '<br>';
    }
   mysqli_close($db);
Could the problem be here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now I know, that the problem occurs only, when the option-list is generated through the SELECT-query and not, when the value are entered directly into the option-list. I think there could be a problem with the quotes, so that only the first word of a term is recognized as value. However, changes of the quotes did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem are the quotes that make words divided by spaces to 1 term:

```
enter code here

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      echo '<option class="optproduct" value='. $row['Name'] . '>' . $row
      ['Name']. '</option>'; echo '<br>'; }
```

becomes to:

```
enter code here

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      echo '<option class="optproduct" value="'. $row['Name'] . '">' . $row
      ['Name']. '</option>'; echo '<br>'; }
```